# Jquery function multiple upload fields add indivdually

Tags: jquery, wordpress, file-upload, contact-form-7

I have a contact form that I have set up using contact form 7 for wordpress. What I would like to know is if there is a function that when the user clicks on an add button a new file upload option appears so they can have a maximum of 5 file upload fields but 1 shows initially and then they add another one as they need it.

I found this: http://kg69design.com/multiple-files-uploading-cf7.html but I can't seem to get it to work

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Yes, just `.hide()` the input and then `.show()` it when a file is attached to the first input. Design your form so that there are 5 File Fields.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the plugin and select contact 7 from plugin.
2. Go to the modules folder.
3. Find the **file.php** and open it in any editor.
4. Copy and paste the below code snippet in line number 45.
5. Multiple file select and upload in now available in your contact form.

`$atts['multiple'] = true;`

Comment: It is not working. It shows an input with "1" inside it.

Answer (score 1):

*Go to the plugin and select contact 7 from plugin.
Go to the modules folder.
Find the file.php and open it in any editor.
Copy and paste the below code snippet in line number 45.
Multiple file select and upload in now available in your contact form.*

This solution does not work. It gives an option for the user to pick multiple files, but when the e-mail arrives you only get one file attached...

Answer (score 1):

I used my theme's "add code to the head" section to inject the code from the website and it started working perfectly.

To answer duplicate_content's question, you need to ensure you have space between the file shortcodes in the file attachments section of CF7. [Mail tab section of CF7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bjvi.jpg)