# Multiple File Upload Contact Form 7

Tags: jquery, upload, contact-form-7

Having read the question here: [Jquery function multiple upload fields add indivdually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933895/jquery-function-multiple-upload-fields-add-indivdually)

There still hasn't been any answer as to how to get the multiple files to actually be delivered to the email client. Does anyone have any insight into avenues I could try to get this to actually work?

Answer (score -2):

I managed to figure this out. You need to ensure there are spaces between the [file] shortcodes in the File Attachments section of CF7 Mail tab.

[image: CF7 Mail tab showing [file] with spaces in between]